# Is it there a Terminal User Interface USB Disks Manager?

Tags: usb, mount, ssh, software-recommendation, tui

I have seen enough answers on how to mount USB Disks via command line but I would like to know if is it there a text tool for managing the USB Drives.

### Scenery

I own a server in a remote place. The server one HDD for the Operating System and Data, and a USB Drive for Backups.

Sometimes I need to remotely (SSH) manage the USB Drive in order to mount/unmount as desired.

It would be useful if we find a text only USB Disk manager.

Thanks in advance.

### Glossary

- "manage" = Mount and Unmount in a visual mode, without doing magic in
  order to guess which /dev/sdX drive is and without having to memorize
  and write every single command in order to mount and unmount.
- "Manage" = Mount and Unmount in a terminal as you do in your favorite
  file browser.

Comment: What exactly do you mean my "manage the USB drive"? If you just need to mount it, why doesn't the normal `mount` command suit your requirements?

Comment: @cocomac "manage" = Mount and Unmount in a visual mode, without doing magic in order to guess which /dev/sdX drive is and without having to memorize and write every single command in order to mount and unmount. "Manage" = Mount and Unmount in a terminal as you do in your favorite file browser. Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure one exists right now, sadly. I might make one later, but AFAIK, that doesn't exist. Look up [the `lsblk` command](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/lsblk.8.html). It will give you a list of block devices (drives) in the system, and how big they are, so that might be enough. But in terms of a real ncurses-style text user interface, I don't know of any that exist

Comment: The question seems unclear without that clarification in the comments -- please edit your question to add your use case.

Comment: There is https://github.com/FedeDP/ncursesFM

Comment: Dear @user535733, yes. That's exactly what I expected as an answer. Thank you very much. I will accept it if you add it as an answer to this question. Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you are using udisks2 you can consider using [udiskie](https://github.com/coldfix/udiskie/wiki) for this.

```
udiskie-info -a
```

This command will show all manageable attached devices. to mount or unmount these devices use these commands:

```
udiskie-mount /dev/device
udiskie-umount /dev/device
```

Where devices are mounted can be specified in a config file for udiskie, default is /media or /run/media.

Comment: I have installed but it shows only device locations, not the actual device's information. Looks useful but -somehow- when I run `udiskie-info -a` I get a list of almost 25 devices when I have only 3 physical devices connected. Thank you.

Comment: use udiskie-info -av for more information about the listed devices. Don't forget to read the manual....

Comment: Thank you Ferdi, but the expected solution is a visual tool, something to just hit *ENTER* or a key in order to do it. The way you just clic on the sidepane in your favorite file browser in order to mount or right click to choose "Safely remove" (unmount). Regards